# gnome-terminal profiles are not being loaded

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

My terminal crashed recently. After the crash, the only terminal profile that is loaded is `unnamed`. I have a Default profile at

```
/home/xxxx/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default
```

It is also recognized by `gconf-editor`, but, it is not being recognized by gnome-terminal or the menu options in the app. How do I get the terminal to recognize my Default profile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gnome terminal settings, including profiles, are now stored in `dconf` instead of `gconf`. While `gconf` used human-readable XML files to store data which could be directly edited, `dconf` settings need to be edited via an interface.

To edit them in a GUI, first install `dconf-tools` (`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`), then run the command `dconf-editor`, and navigate to

```
org > gnome > terminal > legacy > profiles:
```

You'll find all your profiles there, though note that the setting key seems to be a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and the profile name is in the `visible-name` key below.

You can list your profiles using the command:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ | grep -e "\[\:\|visible-name"
```

And you can  dump or load a profile from the command line using the following:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/ > profile.dconf
dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/ < profile.dconf
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, as I no longer have this computer. If someone can confirm this, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @AMB0027: I can confirm this fix! I had corrupted my profile by setting `tmux -2;cd ~/Dev` as the "custom command" to be executed on launch. Then after resetting my command back to just `tmux -2` via dconf-editor I'm now finally able to launch Terminal again!