# Export Ubuntu 16.04 terminal profile

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

How can I export my Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome terminal profile?

The folder `~/.gconf` is empty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need `dconf` to export and import you profile settings. Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/694670/284477) for details (short summary: use `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/ | grep -e "\[\:\|visible-name"` to list the installed profiles, then import/export them via `dconf dump /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:xx-xx-xx-xx/ > sample.dconf` and `dconf load /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:xx-xx-xx-xx/ < sample.dconf`).

Comment: Thanks, do you also know why this doesn't work on MATE Desktop environment or on 14.04?

Comment: @AlexanderZeitler if I understand this correctly `doncf` is part of GNOME 3 (see https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.0/) and MATE Desktop is based on GNOME 2. I suspect your 14.04 setup is also just running an older version of GNOME.

Answer (score 4):

I've wrapped the commands for importing/exporting the default profile into a ready-for-use script, you can get it here: https://github.com/yktoo/yktools/blob/master/gnome-terminal-profile

The usage is straightforward:

```
gnome-terminal-profile export /path/to/file
gnome-terminal-profile import /path/to/file
```